# Forming the general form of parabola

Tags: conic-sections

Suppose the axis of parabola is given by $\alpha x+\beta y+\lambda=0$,
and tangent at vertex is $\beta x-\alpha y+\mu=0$ , now by property of parabola the distance from directrix and from focus are equal , lets assume focus is at a distance "$a$" from the vertex tangent . Now we have that
$\frac{\beta x-\alpha y+\mu+a \sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}}{\left(\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}\right)^{2}}=\sqrt{(x-h)^{2}+(y-k)^{2}}$ where $(h,k)$ is focus location , how do we eliminate h,k as such to get the general form of parabola from here ? As such only equation relating $(h,k)$ is the axis line which is containing that point . Form should look like this : $\left(\frac{\alpha x+\beta y+\lambda}{\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}}\right)^{2}= \frac{1}{√(\alpha^2 + \beta^2)}\left(\frac{\beta x-\alpha y+\mu}{\sqrt{\left(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}\right)}}\right)$

Comment: With directrix $ax+by+c=0$ and focus $F=(h,k)$ the equation of the parabola is $$\frac{(ax+by+c)^2}{a^2+b^2}=(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2\tag1$$

The axis is $bx-ay+d=0,$ where $d$ is determined by the fact that the focus is on the axis. $d=ak-bh.$

The vertex then is determined by the intersection $\langle bx-ay+ak-bh,\frac{(ax+by+c)^2}{a^2+b^2}=(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2\rangle$ or $(x,y)=(-(abk+((-2b^2)-a^2)h+ac)/(2b^2+2a^2),((b^2+2a^2)k-abh-bc)/(2b^2+2a^2)).$

The tangent at vertex goes through the vertex and is parallel to the directrix: $ax+by-(bk+ah-c)/2=0$

 $ax+by-(bk+ah-c)/2=M(bx-ay+ak-bh)^2\tag2$

Comment: Comparing coefficients $(1)=L(2)$

$L = -2c-2kb-2ha, M = 1/(2c+2kb+2ha)$

Making the tangent at vertex form of the equation $$ax+by-(bk+ah-c)/2=(bx-ay+ak-bh)^2/(2c+2kb+2ha)$$ and $(1)$ eqiuvalent, when $-2c-2kb-2ha\neq 0.$

Comment: Nice one @Jan-MagnusØkland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the axis of the parabola to be the  $(x, y) = (h, k) + t (\cos \theta, \sin(\theta) $, where $(h,k)$ is the focus. Then the directrix equation is

$ \cos(\theta) x + \sin(\theta) y = K $

where $ K = -a + h \cos(\theta) + k \sin(\theta) $

The equation of the parabola is

$ (x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = ( \cos(\theta) (x - h) + \sin(\theta) (y - k) +a )^2 $

Comment: Sir then the given form i wrote above is for what 
 (specific focus) parabola ?

Comment: I really have no idea.

Comment: Actually i was going backwards :: the given form was derived by starting from a given parabola of form (alphax+betay)^2 + 2gx +2fy + c= 0 and then converting it to that form . I was just trying to get this form if i know the perpendicular lines and the focus .

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the equations
$$
  u =\alpha x +  \beta y + \lambda
  $$
$$
  v = \beta x - \alpha y + \mu
$$
one can see that the first line is mapped to the $u=0$ coordinate lines and the second to
$v=0$. To ensure that this map preserves distance we need to normalize it:
$$
  u = \frac{1}{{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}} (\alpha x +  \beta y + \lambda)  \\
  $$
$$
  v = \frac{1}{{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}} (\beta x - \alpha y + \mu)
$$
In the $u,v$ plane the equation for the parabola with the focal distance $f$ and the axis
$u=0$ is:
$$
v  = \frac{u^2}{4f}
$$
if we plug in the expressions for $u$ and $v$ we get
$$
\frac{- \alpha y + \beta x + \mu}{\sqrt{\alpha^{2} + \beta^{2}}} -
\frac{\left(\alpha x + \beta y + \lambda\right)^{2}}{4 f \left(\alpha^{2} +
  \beta^{2}\right)} = 0
$$
After getting rid of the denominators we get:
$$
{4 f \sqrt{\alpha^{2} +   \beta^{2}}}
\left({- \alpha y + \beta x + \mu}\right)
  = 
  {\left(\alpha x + \beta y + \lambda\right)^{2}}
$$